# how to copy cart table records into another table?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

am using codeigniter, and am new to codeigniter. i added items into cart table. now i want copy cart records into my `tblShoppingCart` table?

can any one give me example of copying cart records into another table?public

```
function purchase() {
        $userid = $this -> session -> userdata('user_id');
        foreach (serialize($this->cart->contents()) as $cart) {
            $userid = $userid;
            $item_id = $cart['id'];
            $quantity = $cart['qty'];
            $price = $cart['price'];
            $total = $cart['subtotal'];

            $this -> db -> insert('tblShoppingCart', array('tblLoginID' => $userid,'tblItemsID' => $item_id, 'Qty' => $quantity, 'price' => $price, 'total' => $total));
        }
        $this -> cart -> destroy();
        return TRUE;

    }
```

Comment: have you done anything so far??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `$this->cart->contents()`

```
if ($cart = $this->cart->contents()){
            foreach ($cart as $item){
                $order_detail = array(
                    'product_id'    => $item['id'],
                    'pro_quantity'      => $item['qty'],
                    'pro_price'         => $item['price']
                );
                        $this->db->insert('table_Name', $order_detail);
                            } }
```

Comment: i updated question above i added code which i done, and i need insert userid @yadhu Babu